# Iterate and parse XML with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xmlserializer

I'm trying to understand how to parse XML.
This is what I use to write:

```
public static void Write(object data, string fileName)
    {
        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());

        StreamWriter W = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName);
        writer.Serialize(W, data);
        W.Close();
    }
    public static void Write(List<object> data, string fileName)
    {
        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());

        StreamWriter W = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName);
        foreach (object o in data)
        {
            writer.Serialize(W, o);
        }
        W.Close();
    }
```

And, when I want to read, this is what I managed to do so far:

```
public static object Read(string fileName, Type t)
    {
        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(t);

        StreamReader R = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
        object Data = writer.Deserialize(R);
        R.Close();

        return Data;
    }
```

I want to know how to iterate over an XML and obtain the objects, using XmlSerializer and StreamReader. In case it's possible, I don't want to use any other stuff, since I have already understood this.
This is the way I think the method should be:

```
 public static List<Object> Read(string fileName, Type t)
    {
        List<Object> objs = new List<Object>();
        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(t);
        StreamReader R = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
        while(didn't reach the end of the file){
            object Data = writer.Deserialize(R);
            objs.Add(Data);
        }
        R.Close();

        return objs;
    }
```

I've seen many questions here, but I can't understand most of them, besides they use different things to parse and iterate over the XML.
I started with C# a couple of days ago so I don't know much. Any help is appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

So the deserializer will "convert" the xml file into a class that you specify.  So once you deserialize the xml into an instance of your class you will have the values.  No need to iterate unless you have several xml files you need to deserialize into a list of classes.  Here is a simple example that will run in linqpad to show the basic concept.  I prefer DataContractSerializer but the concept is the same.

```
void Main()
{
using (var writer = new FileStream("dog.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    var savedog = new Dog();
    savedog.Breed = "Boxer";
    savedog.Weight = 95;
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dog));
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, savedog);
}

using (var reader = new FileStream("dog.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dog));
    var recalldog = (Dog)serializer.ReadObject(reader);
    Console.WriteLine(recalldog.Breed);
    Console.WriteLine(recalldog.Weight);
}   
}

public class Dog
{
public string Breed { get; set; }
public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It may be obvious, but what are those "var"? Thought they were used in JS only.

Comment: It's just an implicit declaration.  The compiler determines the actual type so it's still strongly typed.  For me it cleans up the code because less typing and a lot of times it makes refactoring easier.